# Gap bug between cells. ios6. UITableView

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, ios7

I have some issues with dynamic cell height. you can see it on screen. Issues highlighted in red. I haven't this issues on IOS 7.

[image]

**UPD.**

heightForRowAtIndexPath method seem like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    Contact* contact = [contacts objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height = 170.0f;
    if (contact.name ==nil) {
        height -=25.0f;
    }
    if (contact.phone ==nil) {
        height -=25.0f;
    }
    if (contact.email==nil) {
        height -=25.0f;
    }
    if (contact.address==nil) {
        height -=40.0f;
    }
    return height;
}
```

But i dunno why it correctly work on iphone 5 with ios7 and not work on iphone 4 with ios6.1.

**UPD2**

layoutSubviews method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    CGFloat phoneY = 65.0f;
    CGFloat emailY = 90.0f;
    CGFloat addressY = 115.0f;

    CGRect contactNameLabelFrame = contactNameLabel.frame;
    CGRect nameLabelFrame = nameLabel.frame;
    CGRect phoneLabelFrame = contactPhoneLabel.frame;
    CGRect phoneButtonFrame = phoneButton.frame;
    CGRect emailButtonFrame = emailButton.frame;
    CGRect emailLabelFrame = contactEmailLabel.frame;
    CGRect addressLabelFrame = contactAddressLabel.frame;
    CGRect addressButtonFrame = addressButton.frame;

    if (contact.name == nil) {
        contactNameLabelFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
        nameLabelFrame.size.width = 0.0f;

        phoneY -=25.0f;
        emailY -= 25.0f;
        addressY -= 25.0f;
    } else {        
        contactNameLabelFrame.size.width = 60.0f;
        nameLabelFrame.size.width = 212.0f;
    }

    if (contact.phone == nil) {
        phoneLabelFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
        phoneButtonFrame.size.width = 0.0f;

        emailY -= 25.0f;
        addressY -= 25.0f;
    } else {
        phoneLabelFrame.size.width = 60.0f;
        phoneLabelFrame.origin.y = phoneY;
        phoneButtonFrame.size.width = 212.0f;
        phoneButtonFrame.origin.y = phoneY - 4;
    }

    if (contact.email == nil) {
        emailLabelFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
        emailButtonFrame.size.width = 0.0f;

        addressY -= 25.0f;
    } else {
        emailLabelFrame.origin.y = emailY;
        emailLabelFrame.size.width = 60.0f;
        emailButtonFrame.origin.y = emailY - 4;
        emailButtonFrame.size.width = 212.0f;
    }

    if (contact.address == nil) {
        addressLabelFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
        addressButtonFrame.size.width = 0.0f;
    } else {
        addressLabelFrame.origin.y = addressY;
        addressLabelFrame.size.width = 60.0f;

        addressButtonFrame.origin.y = addressY + 2;
        addressButtonFrame.size.width = 212.0f;
    }

    [contactNameLabel setFrame:contactNameLabelFrame];
    [nameLabel setFrame:nameLabelFrame];
    [contactPhoneLabel setFrame:phoneLabelFrame];
    [phoneButton setFrame:phoneButtonFrame];
    [contactEmailLabel setFrame:emailLabelFrame];
    [emailButton setFrame:emailButtonFrame];
    [contactAddressLabel setFrame:addressLabelFrame];
    [addressButton setFrame:addressButtonFrame];
}
```

**UPD3**

Thanks all. I found the source of the problem. I add to layoutSubviews method `[super layoutSubviews];`

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it is not likely you will get any help. Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: There appears to be a discrepancy between the calculated cell height and the actual cell height - post your cell layout code as well as the code within `heightForRowAtIndexPath...`!

Comment: It seems to be custom cells, please post the code for the custom cell class, esp where you layout things, set borders etc